# Gender of Stark Direwolves & Daenarys' Dragons

Tags: game-of-thrones

What are the genders of the Direwolves and Dragons in Game Of Thrones?
Lady and Nymeria have female names so they probably are female but what about the rest? Wouldn't it be a little too convenient to have found 6 pups, 4 boys and 2 girls?

Also I know Daenery's Dragons have male names but are we sure they are male? Do dragons have gender?

Comment: There are two questions here. As you can see by the answers provided this could create multiple distinct correct answers. We try to avoid this by only asking one question. I recommend that you split this to ask about the dire wolves and then ask a separate question about the dragons.

Comment: Yes, it is preferred that you ask these as separate questions.

Comment: That seems pedantic for even the strictest of SE communities since these are closely related questions.

Comment: @JesseWilliams look at the two current answers. One does a very good job of answering the dragon question and ignores the wolf question, the other does a good job of answering the wolf question and incorrectly answers the dragon question. Which one should be accepted? That's my point with suggesting that the questions be split.

Comment: No, I definitely understand the issue at hand.  I just don't see it as being an issue.  In fact, there can be multiple correct answers depending on the question and still only one can be correct.  It's in the eye of the beholder (or OP in this case) to determine what is "most right"  :)

Comment: @kuhl incorrect based on what, uncited book info which is unreferenced in the show, of a character that has no first hand knowledge reading from 800+ year old books, and even if we accept it as accurate, it says they are considered male until they lay an egg. The Maester of winter fell told Bran magic is dead, he's clearly wrong.

Comment: @kuhl You could say the same thing about a wolf-only question if someone provided the gender of two and someone else provided the gender of the rest.

Comment: @MatthewRead I personally see a difference in that the dragon gender is a point of contention and the wolves gender is not. Id also argue that one source can be provided for all wolf genders or all dragon genders, but not for both. But the community doesn't seem to agree, so I'll drop it.

Comment: ***too broad - if your question could be answered by an entire book, or has many valid answers, it's probably too broad for our format*** TWO valid answers is not many. And I don't find Maester Aemon reading a book, in the books, to be very convincing evidence, so it's only 1 valid answer of "we don't know for certain about the dragons until proven otherwise". Reopen vote casted.

Comment: OP here, I understand someone saying this question is two different questions, although the argument that this leads to more than two correct answers would also apply if I asked just about the wolves or just about the dragons. More than one answer could be acceptable. I didn't see the point in splitting it up in two, when it was already answered to my satisfaction.

Comment: Sadly, here on StackExchange, "The question has actually been answered perfectly well already" is *never* accepted as evidence that the question is answerable... also voting to reopen!

Answer (score 21):

The direwolves match all of Ned Starks children in gender. This was stated in the first episode. Just like there were five normal pups and one albino runt, with the inverse color of the house being typical for a Bastard in Westerns culture. It's treated like a sign from the Gods to the House Stark, who's sigil is a Grey Direwolf. It's no coincidence, it's magic.

The dragons are all male, simply based on the pronouns used throughout the show. In the books, they are referred to as male. Most telling, the dragons are named after Khal Drogo, and the Khaleesi's brothers (including the one that wore the molten gold crown). **Named after men, not just male sounding names.**

**But this is based on the characters' limiting understanding. It's possible that they are wrong, as many characters are about ancient magic things.** Lizards don't have the easy to spot external sexual traits like mammals would. They could be proven wrong later in the story, as plot demands.

Comment: Is there a source for the gender of the dragons?

Comment: @todd just the pronouns used. Always he never she. I think they also used sons, never sons and daughter.

Comment: @cde "Sons of the Harpy" was happy to employ females. I don't think "sons" vs "sons and daughters" is evidence in this case.

Answer (score 20):

Dragons can switch genders between male and female:

> Dragons, like certain species of amphibeans and fish, can shift gender and have no fixed sex: they can shift back and forth as the needs of the species require for reproduction. However, they are usually referred to as male. Only the ones confirmed to have laid eggs were generally referred to as female.

Source: http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Dragons

According to Maester Aemon reading from the works of Septon Barth:

> “but now one and now the other, as changeable as flame”

Source: A Feast for Crows, Chapter 35, Samwell IV.

Comment: uncited book info which is unreferenced in the show, of a character that has no first hand knowledge reading from 800+ year old books, and even if we accept it as accurate, it says they are considered male until they lay an egg. The Maester of winter fell told Bran magic is dead, he was clearly wrong. Aemon may be wrong, or the priests writing. We won't know until the show positively show that the dragons are/turned female.